# Browse files and subfolders in Python

Tags: python, subdirectory

I'd like to browse through the current folder and all its subfolders and get all the files with .htm|.html extensions. I have found out that it is possible to find out whether an object is a dir or file like this:

```
import os

dirList = os.listdir("./") # current directory
for dir in dirList:
  if os.path.isdir(dir) == True:
    # I don't know how to get into this dir and do the same thing here
  else:
    # I got file and i can regexp if it is .htm|html
```

and in the end, I would like to have all the files and their paths in an array. Is something like that possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to traverse through the files in a directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918458/how-to-traverse-through-the-files-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 171, accepted):

You can use [`os.walk()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) to recursively iterate through a directory and all its subdirectories:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith((".html", ".htm")):
            # whatever
```

To build a list of these names, you can use a list comprehension:

```
htmlfiles = [os.path.join(root, name)
             for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path)
             for name in files
             if name.endswith((".html", ".htm"))]
```

Comment: I think some nuances worth mentioning are that it will traverse/include hidden files, and that this also doesn't resolve links for you. It's also not guaranteed that every file/directory enumerated will exist (mostly due to the fact a link can exist, but its target may not). [Some further reading](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.readlink) about resolving links might be helpful to some, depending on how you intend to use `os.walk`.

Answer (score 18):

I had a similar thing to work on, and this is how I did it.

```
import os

rootdir = os.getcwd()

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        #print os.path.join(subdir, file)
        filepath = subdir + os.sep + file

        if filepath.endswith(".html"):
            print (filepath)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Pragyaditya_Das, brilliant!

Answer (score 8):

In python 3 you can use os.scandir():

```
def dir_scan(path):
    for i in os.scandir(path):
        if i.is_file():
            print('File: ' + i.path)
        elif i.is_dir():
            print('Folder: ' + i.path)
            dir_scan(i.path)
```

Comment: This answer is not very appropriate, because `os.scandir()` does NOT iterate through all the subfolders (as requested in the question). `os.walk()` is better, even in Python 3, as in the accepted answer.

Comment: @DanStowell you were right that it wasn't going through the subfolders I changed my answer so it loops through every file in every subfolder. os.scandir() is supposed to be faster than os.walk() - https://peps.python.org/pep-0471/

Answer (score 5):

Use `newDirName = os.path.abspath(dir)` to create a full directory path name for the subdirectory and then list its contents as you have done with the parent (i.e. `newDirList = os.listDir(newDirName)`)

You can create a separate method of your code snippet and call it recursively through the subdirectory structure. The first parameter is the directory pathname. This will change for each subdirectory.

This answer is based on the 3.1.1 version documentation of the Python Library. There is a good model example of this in action on page 228 of the Python 3.1.1 Library Reference (Chapter 10 - File and Directory Access). 
Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Slightly altered version of Sven Marnach's solution..

```
import os
```

folder_location = 'C:\SomeFolderName'
file_list = create_file_list(folder_location)

def create_file_list(path):
    return_list = []

for filenames in os.walk(path):
    for file_list in filenames:
        for file_name in file_list:
            if file_name.endswith((".txt")):
                return_list.append(file_name)

return return_list

Comment: For some reason there are extra spaces and the for block indentation is not right in the above paste.. SO's markup does not like me..

Comment: Poor rework of simple code - replacing tuple assignment with embedded loops makes code less readable, and probably less efficient too

Comment: Thanks for the comment @volcano.. The example above did not seem to work hence the additional for loop..

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways works for me.

```
1. Work with the `os` package and use `'__file__'` to replace the main 
directory when the project locates

import os
script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)      

path = 'subdirectory/test.txt'
file = os.path.join(script_dir, path)
fileread = open(file,'r') 


2. By using '\\' to read or write the file in subfolder 
fileread = open('subdirectory\\test.txt','r')
```

Comment: Do not paste the same [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73091606/7758804) to multiple questions. This has been flagged to a moderator.