# How to list all folders and files recursively?

Tags: python-2.7

How can I get folders and files **including** files/folders of subdirectories in python?
I need the absolute path of each file/folder.

I want to rename all folders and files. So I have to rename the folders first.

```
folder
-- file
-- folder1
---- folder1.1
------ file
------ folder1.1.1
-------- file
-- folder2
---- ...
```

Comment: Take a look [here][1] it was already answered before 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817209/browse-files-and-subfolders-in-python

Comment: That is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 7):

I took a quick look around and found out its pretty easy. From [Sven Marnach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5817256/4518341):

> You can us [`os.walk()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk)
>   to recursively iterate through a directory and all its subdirectories:
>
> ```
> for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
>     for name in files:
>         if name.endswith((".html", ".htm")):
>             # whatever
> ```
>
> To build a list of these names, you can use a list comprehension:
>
> ```
> htmlfiles = [os.path.join(root, name)
>              for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path)
>              for name in files
>              if name.endswith((".html", ".htm"))]
> ```

Comment: @Lucas What OS are you running?

Comment: Windows 8. Target will be CentOS 6.5 that scans a NFS share on a Windows Server. Paths will be like /mnt/nfs/share/foo/bar/foo/bar

Comment: @Lucas Can't you go into it manually and select the folders then rename them by right clicking?

Comment: I could but there will be spawn every day MANY folders that have to be renamed.

Comment: @Lucas If theres a bunch just hold SHIFT and go from top to bottom. It'll do all of them so you can rename with one click