# How to rename the files of different format from the same folder but different subfolder using python

Tags: python-3.x

I have one scenario where i have to rename the files in the folder. Please find the scenario,

Example :

```
Elements(Main Folder)<br/>
    2(subfolder-1) <br/>
       sample_2_description.txt(filename1)<br/>
       sample_2_video.avi(filename2)<br/>
    3(subfolder2)
       sample_3_tag.jpg(filename1)<br/>
       sample_3_analysis.GIF(filename2)<br/>
       sample_3_word.docx(filename3)<br/>
```

I want to modify the names of the files as,

```
Elements(Main Folder)<br/>
    2(subfolder1)<br/>
       description.txt(filename1)<br/>
       video.avi(filename2)<br/>
    3(subfolder2)
       tag.jpg(filename1)<br/>
       analysis.GIF(filename2)<br/>
       word.docx(filename3)<br/>
```

Could anyone guide on how to write the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursive directory traversal to rename a file can be based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37014760/recursively-rename-file-extensions) answer. All we are required to do is to replace the file name instead of the extension in the accepted answer.

Here is one way - split the file name by `_` and use the last index of the split list as the new name

```py
import os
import sys

directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath("/path/to/parent/folder")) #get the directory of your script
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in files:
        subdirectoryPath = os.path.relpath(subdir, directory) #get the path to your subdirectory
        filePath = os.path.join(subdirectoryPath, filename) #get the path to your file
        newFilePath = filePath.split("_")[-1] #create the new name by splitting the old name by _ and grabbing last index
        os.rename(filePath, newFilePath) #rename your file
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have tried to execute the code and customized the code. I am getting the error like this
"FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'BUG_10_ALM_snapshot_5.jpg' -> 'ALM_snapshot_5.jpg'"
I am having the respective file in that particular folder but getting this error.
Could you please help.@saurjog

Comment: @Aishwarya could you elaborate? What is the structure of the directory?

Answer (score -1):

check below code example for the first filename1, replace path with the actual path of the file:

```
import os

os.rename(r'path\\sample_2_description.txt',r'path\\description.txt')
print("File Renamed!")
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.The code which you have mentioned has for the single files or we can use the above method for changing 5 to 10 files names.But I am having above 1000 files which are to be renamed.