# How to read Images from multiple folders?

Tags: python, image-processing

I am working with mammogram images. I have 3 folders with each folder consisting of 40 images. I want to read images from each folders so that I can extract features from each of the image and store them in a variable.

I don't know as how can I read images from multiple folders. It would be really helpful if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: get a list of folders and use os.listdir or os.walk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `os.walk` to recursively traverse a directory, and `PIL` to handle images.

```
import os
from PIL import Image

for path, _, files in os.walk('.')
    for file in files:
        foo = Image.open(file) 
        # now do something with the image
```

Comment: Just a clueless individual asking here: what are `src` and `i` here?

Comment: @BowenLiu pretty sure it's a typo, I hope I'm not messing things here, the answer is nearly 3 years old

Answer (score 0):

Hope This can be helpful

[Browse files and subfolders in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817209/browse-files-and-subfolders-in-python)

http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-traverse-a-directory-tree-in-python-guide-to-os-walk/

Comment: Please be aware that *"link only"* answers are frowned upon.