# how I can browse a file directory(path) from a parameter pass?

Tags: python

I am beginner in python ,  I need a help please:

First  i try to pass the path of a dataset in parameter.

I like to know how I can browse the dataset from this path.

this My code

```
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Initialize the parser
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="my math script"**strong text**

    )

    # Add the parameters positional/optional
    parser.add_argument('-input','--d', help="path to input database mat file", type=str)



    # Parse the arguments
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "browse"? Following `yourscript.py -d /path/to/database`, the value of `args.d` will be `/path/to/database`. Use `args.d` as you would any other variable.

Comment: Welcome! It's unclear what you're asking. Do you want to open a file? Or are you having trouble getting the path from args?

Comment: Do you want to browse a directory for its content? This question has been already answered:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817209/browse-files-and-subfolders-in-python

Comment: no already i get the path,  now i need to do a for boucle to process all the image in the path entered