# Adding a PDF page to many PDF files in different folders

Tags: python, pdf

I would like to add a PDF page (always the same => C:\Files\page2.pdf) to all PDF files of my folders and subfolders:

I sometimes use this PowerShell command to find and replace some files by specific ones:

```
replace "C:\PDF\*.pdf" "C:\Folders" /s
```

I would like a Python script able to find all my PDFs in my folders/subfolders (C:\Folders.. with many PDF with 1 page) and to merge a second page (C:\Files\page2.pdf) into all PDFs keeping their path and names.

Something like this:

```
merge "C:\Folders\*.pdf" with "C:\Files\page2.pdf"
```

Do you have any idea to do that simply?

- I have to generate these PDF files every month
- It's difficult for me to add a PDF library (it will be run on a server)
- I have thousands of PDFs to merge and they are in many different folders

Comment: you could try [`pypdf`](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) (it's written in pure Python) and for `os`-stuffs have a look at the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk), and for [scheduling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Jorj McKie and a [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817209/browse-files-and-subfolders-in-python) from @Sven Marnach the code below do exactly what I wanted :-)

```
import fitz  # PyMuPDF
import os
import pathlib

pdffiles = [os.path.join(root, name)
             for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"C:\Folders")
             for name in files
             if name.endswith((".pdf"))]

src = fitz.open(r"C:\page2.pdf")  # the PDF with that single page
for f in pdffiles:
    stream = pathlib.Path(f).read_bytes()  # read PDF into memory
    doc=fitz.open("pdf", stream)  # open as a PDF from memory
    doc.insert_pdf(src)  # append the page
    doc.ez_save(f)  # save PDF with page now appended
```

Thank you Jorj !

Bonus :

My pdf to modify as 1 page and I may have to add 1 page before and 1 page after, here is how I did :

```
pdffiles = [os.path.join(root, name)
             for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"C:\Folders")
             for name in files
             if name.endswith((".pdf"))]

src1 = fitz.open(r"C:\Files\page1.pdf")  # the PDF with page 1
src3 = fitz.open(r"C:\Files\page3.pdf")  # the PDF with page 3
for f in pdffiles:
    stream = pathlib.Path(f).read_bytes()  # read PDF into memory
    doc=fitz.open("pdf", stream)  # open as a PDF from memory
    doc.insert_pdf(src1, start_at=0)
    doc.insert_pdf(src3)
    doc.ez_save(f)  # save PDF with page now appended
```

Comment: Thank you [Maxence](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21413288/maxence-melin)! Any comments on the performance?

Comment: It's quick ! In my test more than 5000 pdf among 36 folders have been modified in less than 2 min

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do this with PyMuPDF:

```py
import fitz  # PyMuPDF
import os
import pathlib
folders = "c:/Folders"
filelist = [f for f in os.listdir(folders) if f.endswith(".pdf")]
src = fitz.open("c:/files/page2.pdf")  # the PDF with that single page
for f in filelist:
    filename = os.path.join(folders, f)
    stream = pathlib.Path(filename).read_bytes()  # read PDF into memory
    doc=fitz.open("pdf", stream)  # open as a PDF from memory
    doc.insert_pdf(src)  # append the page
    doc.ez_save(filename)  # save PDF with page now appended
    doc.close()
```

The fastest solution you can find ...
If "C:\Files\page2.pdf" contains more than 1 page, you can also sub-select the required one.

**Note:** I am a maintainer and the original creator of [PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/).

Comment: should file descriptors  be close in `PyMudPDF`, right? (or use a context manager)

Comment: Hi Jorj ! Thank you for your answer. I installed PyMuPDF on my laptop and try to use your code but without any success (npath doesn't seem to deal with a list of directories): 
filelist = [f for f in os.path.listdir(r"C:\Users\4499SU\OneDrive - GRTgaz\Bureau\Test_py_pdf\Folders") if f.endswith(".pdf")]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'ntpath' has no attribute 'listdir'. Did you mean: 'isdir'?

Comment: If it can help, my pdf are always in subfolders named "PDF" which are themselves in subfolders with always changing names

Comment: My bad: correct is `os.listdir()`. Please look at the corrected version above.