How do I list all the file from one subdirectory from a list of subdirectories
I am trying to list files by their directory and do something with files and go to next directory
this is the folder tree
root
   div1
      subdiv1
         up1
           d1s1u1_1.file
           d1s1u1_2.file
         up2
           d1s1u2_1.file
           d1s1u2_2.file
      subdiv2
         up1
           d1s2u1_1.file
           d1s2u1_2.file
         up2
           d1s2u2_1.file
           d1s2u2_2.file
   div2
      subdiv1
         up1
           d2s1u1_1.file
           d2s1u1_2.file
         up2
           d2s1u2_1.file
           d2s1u2_2.file
      subdiv2
         up1
           d2s2u1_1.file
           d2s2u1_2.file
         up2
           d2s2u2_1.file
           d2s2u2_2.file

   div3
      subdiv1
         up1
           d3s1u1_1.file
           d3s1u1_2.file
         up2
           d3s1u2_1.file
           d3s1u2_2.file
      subdiv2
         up1
           d3s2u1_1.file
           d3s2u1_2.file
         up2
           d3s2u2_1.file
           d3s2u2_2.file

how do I list files under up1 of div1 do something to the listed files and go to up2 and do the same thing for rest of the divs

Probably you can use one of the solutions listed here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817209/browse-files-and-subfolders-in-python

I want to know which folder I am in while browsing the files and list out the files inside that folder do something to the list and go to the next folder

glob.glob() can glob for you, which is almost-certainly what you're after
from glob import iglob
from pathlib import Path
for path in map(Path, iglob("root/**/*.file")):
    # opportunity to test proprties of `path`
    # work with `path` here

You can go "up" relatively with ../ (or start from a fully-defined path /foo/bar) and it supports wildcard * and globstar **
os.walk() can also be used, but it's generally less desirable as it requires tracking the tree position and building complete paths yourself

can you elaborate your answer please? how do i list the two files from up1 do some thing to the listed files and go to up2 subsequently?

sorry, fast fingers - I added much more content .. you could, for example, match like /root/**/up1/* if you wanted all the paths which had up1, or /root/*/*/up1/* if you know exactly the depth already (which is probably the case)

I think I was unable to ask the question correctly! I want to go endpoint of a directory tree and list out the files of that directory. Please note that I don't know the directory name. There are almost thousand directory endpoints

if you just want everything with the extension .file, something like **/*.file is probably sufficient .. if you wanted all the files, then **/*

if you want to do more advanced path features, map each to a pathlib.Path, which will let you test like is_file() https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.is_file

here is how I solved the problem
import os
fol = r"path/to/my/dir"
path_list = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(fol):
    for f in files:
        if root not in path_list:
            path_list.append(root) 


for path in path_list:
    print(path, os.listdir(path))

