# How to get r/w permission for a directory for a particular user?

Tags: python, windows

My python script creates a folder, one for each user. I want to make permissions/grant privileges where only one particular user can have access to only one specific directory and not to other folders. For example, python script creates folder1, folder 2, ...I want folder1 to be readable by user 1 only, and folder2 only by user2 ...etc. Working on Windows Server 2008.
Thank you.

Comment: Try os.chown followed by os.chmod

Answer (score 0):

`os.chown(path, uid, gid)` to change the path owner, and then `os.chmod(path, mode)` with mode 700 (Only you can read, write to, or execute the path). I think that should work..

---EDIT---

apparantly `chown` dosent work for windows. looks like you will need the `win32security` module, which is a part of pywin32. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168110/setting-folder-permissions-in-windows-using-python) is an answer demonstrating how to change permissions with it.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - the docs state this about chomd: "Availability: Unix, Windows." - see http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chmod

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - wait, chown is only for Unix apparantly.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Win32 security APIs are not for the faint hearted.  The simplest solution is to use an external Microsoft program like `cacls` or `icacls` called from Python, using `subprocess` or `system`.  `cacls` is rather messy:

```
cmd = r"echo y|cacls gash.txt /E /G BUILTIN\\Users:R"
```

`cacls` is documented in the online help (Windows XP) and [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162786/en-us).  It may output a prompt (depending on the action) "Are you sure (Y/N)?", which is why we have the `echo y|` in the example (see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/135268)).  Alternatively use `xcacls.exe` from the Windows Resource Kit - this version does not prompt.

At Windows Vista and Windows 7 the `cacls` program still works but is deprecated in favour of the more powerful `icacls` program, which thankfully does not prompt.  Sorry, I don't have Windows 8.

Comment: the question is tagged windows.