# How to authorize/deny write access to a directory on Windows using Python?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, authorization

I would like to be able to authorize or deny write access to a specific directory on Windows XP and more.

I tried the following, and they all don't work:

- `os.chmod()`: only a file read-only attribute can be specified, see [Python's doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chmod)
- `win32api.SetFileAttribute()` *FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY: A file that is read-only. [...] This attribute is not honored on directories*, see [MSDN's SetFileAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

It looks like the only alternative I have is to access and update the "[Security info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379579.aspx)" of the directory, I've tried for several hours to get something done with this without much success (I'm really unfamiliar with Win32 API).

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Win32 too, but there might be something in the [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) library that can help you.

Comment: There are functions to update the "Security info" in pywin32, but there are too many concepts, flags and hoops that I'm unfamiliar with. Plus the pywin32 documentation is barely helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was just challenging thing to do. I've started with [this really great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12168268/1149736) which helps you with a similar thing.

You can start by just listing ACLs for directory, which could be done using this code:

```python
import win32security
import ntsecuritycon as con

FILENAME = r'D:\tmp\acc_test' 

sd = win32security.GetFileSecurity(FILENAME, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
dacl = sd.GetSecurityDescriptorDacl()

ace_count = dacl.GetAceCount()
print('Ace count:', ace_count)

for i in range(0, ace_count):
    rev, access, usersid = dacl.GetAce(i)
    user, group, type  = win32security.LookupAccountSid('', usersid)
    print('User: {}/{}'.format(group, user), rev, access)
```

You can find method [`PyACL.GetAceCount()`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.2/pywin32/PyACL__GetAceCount_meth.html) which returns number of ACEs.

The [`GetAce(i)`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.2/pywin32/PyACL__GetAce_meth.html) function returns [`ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE` header](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374847(v=vs.85).aspx) as a `tuple`:

- [`ACE_HEADER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374919(v=vs.85).aspx) - two integers `AceType`, `AceFlags` - trial and error showed me that `AceFlags` set to `11` meant inherit privileges and `3` not inherited
- [`ACCESS_MASK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374892(v=vs.85).aspx) - detailed [list here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21321743/1149736) or in [`ntsecuritycon.py`](http://pyxr.sourceforge.net/PyXR/c/python24/lib/site-packages/win32/lib/ntsecuritycon.py.html)
- `SID`

Now you are able to read old ACEs and [deleting old ones](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.2/pywin32/PyACL__DeleteAce_meth.html) is quite simple:

```python
for i in range(0, ace_count):
    dacl.DeleteAce(0)
```

And after that you can just add privileges by calling [`AddAccessAllowedAceEx()`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.2/pywin32/PyACL__AddAccessAllowedAceEx_meth.html) [[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374951(v=vs.85).aspx)]:

```python
userx, domain, type = win32security.LookupAccountName ("", "your.user")
usery, domain, type = win32security.LookupAccountName ("", "other.user")

dacl.AddAccessAllowedAceEx(win32security.ACL_REVISION, 3, 2032127, userx) # Full control
dacl.AddAccessAllowedAceEx(win32security.ACL_REVISION, 3, 1179785, usery) # Read only

sd.SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(1, dacl, 0)   # may not be necessary
win32security.SetFileSecurity(FILENAME, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, sd)
```

I've taken numbers `3`, `2032127` and `1179785` from the listing in first half of the script (before running the script I've set up privileges in *Explorer->Right Click->Properties->Security->Advanced*):

[image: Explorer->Right Click->Properties->Security->Advanced]

<sup>Just illustrative image borrowed from http://technet.microsoft.com/</sup>

```
User: DOMAIN/user (0, 3) 2032127
User: DOMAIN/user2 (0, 3) 1179785
```

But it corresponds to:

- *3* -> `OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE|CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE`
- *2032127* -> `FILE_ALL_ACCESS` (well, actually `con.FILE_ALL_ACCESS = 2032639`, but once you apply it on file and read it back you'll get *2032127*; the difference is *512 - 0x0200* - the constant I haven't found in [`ntsecuritycon.py/file security permissions`](http://pyxr.sourceforge.net/PyXR/c/python24/lib/site-packages/win32/lib/ntsecuritycon.py.html#0021))
- *1179785* -> `FILE_GENERIC_READ`

You can also remove access, change it or remove it but this should be very solid start for you.

---

#### TL;DR - codes

```python
import win32security
import ntsecuritycon as con

FILENAME = r'D:\tmp\acc_test'

userx, domain, type = win32security.LookupAccountName ("", "your.user")
usery, domain, type = win32security.LookupAccountName ("", "other.user")

sd = win32security.GetFileSecurity(FILENAME, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
dacl = sd.GetSecurityDescriptorDacl()

ace_count = dacl.GetAceCount()
print('Ace count:', ace_count)

# Listing
for i in range(0, ace_count):
    rev, access, usersid = dacl.GetAce(i)
    user, group, type  = win32security.LookupAccountSid('', usersid)

    print('User: {}/{}'.format(group, user), rev, access)

# Removing the old ones
for i in range(0, ace_count):
    dacl.DeleteAce(0)

# Add full control for user x
dacl.AddAccessAllowedAceEx(win32security.ACL_REVISION, 
    con.OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE|con.CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE, con.FILE_ALL_ACCESS, userx)

# Add read only access for user y
dacl.AddAccessAllowedAceEx(win32security.ACL_REVISION, 
    con.OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE|con.CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE, con.FILE_GENERIC_READ, usery)

sd.SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(1, dacl, 0)   # may not be necessary
win32security.SetFileSecurity(FILENAME, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, sd)
```

---

#### Mini utility for complete ACE listing

I just wrote small script for parsing all file ACEs:

```python
import win32security
import ntsecuritycon as con
import sys


# List of all file masks that are interesting
ACCESS_MASKS = ['FILE_READ_DATA', 'FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY', 'FILE_WRITE_DATA', 'FILE_ADD_FILE', 
                     'FILE_APPEND_DATA', 'FILE_ADD_SUBDIRECTORY', 'FILE_CREATE_PIPE_INSTANCE', 'FILE_READ_EA',
                     'FILE_WRITE_EA', 'FILE_EXECUTE', 'FILE_TRAVERSE', 'FILE_DELETE_CHILD', 
                     'FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES', 'FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES', 'FILE_ALL_ACCESS', 'FILE_GENERIC_READ',
                     'FILE_GENERIC_WRITE', 'FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE'] 

# List of all inheritance flags
ACE_FLAGS = ['OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE', 'CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE', 'NO_PROPAGATE_INHERIT_ACE', 'INHERIT_ONLY_ACE']

# List of all ACE types
ACE_TYPES = ['ACCESS_MIN_MS_ACE_TYPE', 'ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE', 'ACCESS_DENIED_ACE_TYPE', 'SYSTEM_AUDIT_ACE_TYPE',
             'SYSTEM_ALARM_ACE_TYPE', 'ACCESS_MAX_MS_V2_ACE_TYPE', 'ACCESS_ALLOWED_COMPOUND_ACE_TYPE',
             'ACCESS_MAX_MS_V3_ACE_TYPE', 'ACCESS_MIN_MS_OBJECT_ACE_TYPE', 'ACCESS_ALLOWED_OBJECT_ACE_TYPE',
             'ACCESS_DENIED_OBJECT_ACE_TYPE', 'SYSTEM_AUDIT_OBJECT_ACE_TYPE', 'SYSTEM_ALARM_OBJECT_ACE_TYPE',
             'ACCESS_MAX_MS_OBJECT_ACE_TYPE', 'ACCESS_MAX_MS_V4_ACE_TYPE', 'ACCESS_MAX_MS_ACE_TYPE',
             'ACCESS_ALLOWED_CALLBACK_ACE_TYPE', 'ACCESS_DENIED_CALLBACK_ACE_TYPE', 'ACCESS_ALLOWED_CALLBACK_OBJECT_ACE_TYPE',
             'ACCESS_DENIED_CALLBACK_OBJECT_ACE_TYPE', 'SYSTEM_AUDIT_CALLBACK_ACE_TYPE', 'SYSTEM_ALARM_CALLBACK_ACE_TYPE',
             'SYSTEM_AUDIT_CALLBACK_OBJECT_ACE_TYPE', 'SYSTEM_ALARM_CALLBACK_OBJECT_ACE_TYPE', 'SYSTEM_MANDATORY_LABEL_ACE_TYPE',
             'ACCESS_MAX_MS_V5_ACE_TYPE']

################################################################################
def get_ace_types_str(ace_type):
    ''' Yields all matching ACE types as strings
    '''
    for t in ACE_TYPES:
        if getattr(con, t) == ace_type:
            yield t

################################################################################
def get_ace_flags_str(ace_flag):
    ''' Yields all matching ACE flags as strings 
    '''
    for t in ACE_FLAGS:
        attr = getattr(con, t)
        if (attr & ace_flag) == attr:
            yield t

################################################################################
def get_access_mask_str(access_mask):
    ''' Yields all matching ACE flags as strings 
    '''
    for t in ACCESS_MASKS:
        attr = getattr(con, t)
        if (attr & access_mask) == attr:
            yield t

################################################################################
def list_file_ace(filename):
    ''' Method for listing of file ACEs
    '''

    # Load data
    sd = win32security.GetFileSecurity(filename, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
    dacl = sd.GetSecurityDescriptorDacl()     

    # Print ACE count
    ace_count = dacl.GetAceCount()
    print('File', filename, 'has', ace_count, 'ACEs')

    # Go trough individual ACEs
    for i in range(0, ace_count):
        (ace_type, ace_flag), access_mask, usersid = dacl.GetAce(i)
        user, group, usertype = win32security.LookupAccountSid('', usersid)

        print('\tUser: {}\\{}'.format(group, user))    
        print('\t\tACE Type ({}):'.format(ace_type), '; '.join(get_ace_types_str(ace_type))) 
        print('\t\tACE Flags ({}):'.format(ace_flag), ' | '.join(get_ace_flags_str(ace_flag)))
        print('\t\tAccess Mask ({}):'.format(access_mask), ' | '.join(get_access_mask_str(access_mask)))
        print()


################################################################################
# Execute with some defaults
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
        list_file_ace(filename)
        print()
```

It prints out strings like this:

```
D:\tmp>acc_list.py D:\tmp D:\tmp\main.bat
File D:\tmp has 8 ACEs
        User: BUILTIN\Administrators
                ACE Type (0): ACCESS_MIN_MS_ACE_TYPE; ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE
                ACE Flags (0):
                Access Mask (2032127): FILE_READ_DATA | FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY | FILE_WRITE_DATA | FILE_ADD_FILE | FILE_APPEND_DATA | FILE_ADD_SUBDIRECTORY | FILE_CREATE_PIPE_INSTANCE | FILE_READ_EA | FILE_WRITE_EA | FILE_EXECUTE | FILE_TRAVERSE | FILE_DELETE_CHILD | FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES | FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES | FILE_GENERIC_READ | FILE_GENERIC_WRITE | FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE

...
```

Comment: Wow, I built something extremely similar a few hours ago! I'm going to post it somewhere for reference, but yours is quite nice! Thanks!

Comment: As I said in my reply below, I'd like to restore the ACL in the end. Deleting everything and adding only the ones I want isn't very nice, but I guess I can keep a reference of some sort towards the "deny write" ACE somewhere, and try to find it and delete it when I'm done...

Comment: @multani storing ACEs and restoring them in the end is pretty easy I think. I've just played around with different methods. You can use complex conditions to (not) select which ACEs to keep/delete.

Comment: It seems that this should be a package on PyPI somewhere!

Answer (score 2):

So, by pocking around and trying to understand what was going on, I managed to find something very similar to what @Vyktor posted before.

I found some help using [this example](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/source/browse/src/python/pywin32/PLATLIB/win32/Demos/security/setnamedsecurityinfo.py?repo=xy-27&r=b92705dfbb538e51c450cb5592e64acbe42c21d6).

So, first thing I did was to try to understand the flags set by Windows when I was manually changing the security information with the GUI, I built a set of function to help me with this:

```python
import os

import win32con
import win32security
import win32process
import ntsecuritycon

d = "toto"
f = os.path.join(d, "foo")


def build_flags_map(*attrs, **kw):
    mod = kw.get('mod', win32con)

    r = {}
    for attr in attrs:
        value = getattr(mod, attr)
        r[value] = attr
    return r


ACE_TYPE = build_flags_map('ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE', 'ACCESS_DENIED_ACE_TYPE')

ACCESS_MASK = build_flags_map(
    'GENERIC_WRITE', 'GENERIC_ALL', 'GENERIC_EXECUTE', 'GENERIC_READ',
    'WRITE_OWNER', 'DELETE', 'READ_CONTROL', 'SYNCHRONIZE', 'WRITE_DAC',
    'ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY')

ACCESS_MASK_FILES = build_flags_map(
        'FILE_ADD_FILE', 'FILE_READ_DATA', 'FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY',
        'FILE_WRITE_DATA', 'FILE_ADD_FILE', 'FILE_APPEND_DATA',
        'FILE_ADD_SUBDIRECTORY', 'FILE_CREATE_PIPE_INSTANCE', 'FILE_READ_EA',
        'FILE_WRITE_EA', 'FILE_EXECUTE', 'FILE_TRAVERSE', 'FILE_DELETE_CHILD',
        'FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES', 'FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES', 'FILE_ALL_ACCESS',
        'FILE_GENERIC_READ', 'FILE_GENERIC_WRITE', 'FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE',
        mod=ntsecuritycon,
    )

ACE_FLAGS = build_flags_map(
    'CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE', 'INHERITED_ACE', 'FAILED_ACCESS_ACE_FLAG',
    'INHERIT_ONLY_ACE', 'OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE',
    mod=win32security)


def display_flags(map, value):
    r = []
    for flag, name in map.items():
        if flag & value:
            r.append(name)
            value = value - flag

    if value != 0:
        # We didn't specified all the flags in the mapping :(
        r.append('(flags left 0x%x)' % value)

    return r' | '.join(r)


def show_acls(path):

    process_handler = win32process.GetCurrentProcess()
    thread_handler = win32security.OpenProcessToken(
            process_handler,
            win32security.TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS)
    current_sid = win32security.GetTokenInformation(thread_handler, win32security.TokenUser)[0]

    desc = win32security.GetNamedSecurityInfo(
            path,
            win32security.SE_FILE_OBJECT,
            win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION)    

    dacl = desc.GetSecurityDescriptorDacl()

    print("%d ACE on %s" % (dacl.GetAceCount(), path))
    for i in range(0, dacl.GetAceCount()):

        ace = dacl.GetAce(i)
        (ace_type, ace_flags), ace_mask, ace_sid = ace

        if ace_sid == current_sid:
            user = "me"
        else:
            user = str(ace_sid)

        print("  User: %s =>\n"
              "      ACE type: %s\n"
              "      ACE flags: %s\n"
              "      ACE mask: %s\n"
              "      Raw ACE: %r\n" % (
              user,
              ACE_TYPE[ace_type],
              display_flags(ACE_FLAGS, ace_flags),
              display_flags(ACCESS_MASK_FILES, ace_mask),
              ace))
```

From there, I got the following informations:

```
7 ACE on toto
  User: me =>
      ACE type: ACCESS_DENIED_ACE_TYPE
      ACE flags: CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE | OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE
      ACE mask: FILE_ADD_FILE | FILE_CREATE_PIPE_INSTANCE | FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES | FILE_WRITE_EA
      Raw ACE: ((1, 3), 278, <PySID object at 0x00B02148>)

  User: me =>
      ACE type: ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE
      ACE flags: INHERITED_ACE
      ACE mask: FILE_TRAVERSE | FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY | FILE_ADD_FILE | FILE_CREATE_PIPE_INSTANCE | FILE_READ_EA | FILE_DELETE_CHILD | FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES | FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE | FILE_WRITE_EA | FILE_ALL_ACCESS | (flags left 0x-12039f)
      Raw ACE: ((0, 16), 2032127, <PySID object at 0x00A6FBF0>)

  User: me =>
      ACE type: ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE
      ACE flags: INHERITED_ACE | CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE | INHERIT_ONLY_ACE | OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE
      ACE mask: (flags left 0x10000000)
      Raw ACE: ((0, 27), 268435456, <PySID object at 0x00B02148>)

  User: PySID:S-1-5-18 =>
      ACE type: ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE
      ACE flags: INHERITED_ACE
      ACE mask: FILE_TRAVERSE | FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY | FILE_ADD_FILE | FILE_CREATE_PIPE_INSTANCE | FILE_READ_EA | FILE_DELETE_CHILD | FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES | FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE | FILE_WRITE_EA | FILE_ALL_ACCESS | (flags left 0x-12039f)
      Raw ACE: ((0, 16), 2032127, <PySID object at 0x00A6FBF0>)

  User: PySID:S-1-5-18 =>
      ACE type: ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE
      ACE flags: INHERITED_ACE | CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE | INHERIT_ONLY_ACE | OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE
      ACE mask: (flags left 0x10000000)
      Raw ACE: ((0, 27), 268435456, <PySID object at 0x00B02148>)

  User: PySID:S-1-5-32-544 =>
      ACE type: ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE
      ACE flags: INHERITED_ACE
      ACE mask: FILE_TRAVERSE | FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY | FILE_ADD_FILE | FILE_CREATE_PIPE_INSTANCE | FILE_READ_EA | FILE_DELETE_CHILD | FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES | FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE | FILE_WRITE_EA | FILE_ALL_ACCESS | (flags left 0x-12039f)
      Raw ACE: ((0, 16), 2032127, <PySID object at 0x00A6FBF0>)

  User: PySID:S-1-5-32-544 =>
      ACE type: ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE
      ACE flags: INHERITED_ACE | CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE | INHERIT_ONLY_ACE | OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE
      ACE mask: (flags left 0x10000000)
      Raw ACE: ((0, 27), 268435456, <PySID object at 0x00B02148>)
```

This example shows the default ACL I have on my system + the first one, which is one I created myself and which denies writes on the directory.

So,using the example before, I built this:

```
def pipe_str_flags(map, *flags):
    r = 0
    reverse_map = dict((value, key) for key, value in map.items())
    for flag in flags:
        r = r | reverse_map[flag]
    return r

def forbid_write(path):
    security_info = win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION

    process_handler = win32process.GetCurrentProcess()
    thread_handler = win32security.OpenProcessToken(
            process_handler,
            win32security.TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS)

    desc = win32security.GetNamedSecurityInfo(
            path,
            win32security.SE_FILE_OBJECT,
            security_info)    

    current_sid = win32security.GetTokenInformation(thread_handler, win32security.TokenUser)[0]
    dacl = desc.GetSecurityDescriptorDacl()

    mask = pipe_str_flags(ACCESS_MASK_FILES,
            'FILE_ADD_FILE',
            'FILE_CREATE_PIPE_INSTANCE',
            'FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES',
            'FILE_WRITE_EA')

    ace_flags = pipe_str_flags(ACE_FLAGS,
            'CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE',
            'OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE')

    dacl.AddAccessDeniedAceEx(
            dacl.GetAclRevision(),
            ace_flags,
            mask,
            current_sid)

    win32security.SetNamedSecurityInfo(
        path,
        win32security.SE_FILE_OBJECT,
        security_info,
        None,
        None,
        dacl,
        None)
```

Contrary to @Vyktor solution, I'm using a "Denied" ACE, by denying write access (whereas Vyktor added an "Allowed read-only" ACE).

I sitll miss a proper way to remove this ACE so I can write again in this directory, but I haven't really look yet. One thing which is important is that "Denied" ACE have priority over "Allowed" ACE, so I tried the naive way of using `dacl.AddAccessAllowedAceEx()` with the exact same parameters as I was using on `dacl.AddAccessDeniedAceEx()`, but the later one has precedence over the former one, so I still can't write into the directory.

Comment: 8 years later: I believe to delete the ACE Vykor did: `for i in range(0, ace_count): dacl.DeleteAce(0)`. So you'd have to get the ACE number, and delete it... Check out http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/PyACL.html - I revised Vyktor's answer (hopefully gets approved) which reflects some of what you said (which wasn't intentional), updated his links, and what not. Your work looks impressive - win32api is slightly annoying to deal with.