# Chmod issue to change file permission using python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, chmod

I am looking to change the file permission to all files to read write and execute for all the users in a directory using a python script. However, after running the script when I check the file permission doing the right click, it only shows the permissions for me and for the group everyone it only has read permission. Is there anything wrong I am doing in the following script:

```
import os
import pdb

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('M:\intra\EU'):
    for filename in filenames:
        path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        os.chmod(path, 0o777) # for example
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found a solution here :)

[Setting folder permissions in Windows using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168110/setting-folder-permissions-in-windows-using-python)

```
import win32security
import ntsecuritycon as con
import os
import pdb
userx, domain, type = win32security.LookupAccountName ("", "Everyone")
directory='M:\intra\EU'
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('M:\intra\EU'):
    for FILENAME in filenames:
        sd = win32security.GetFileSecurity(directory+'\\'+FILENAME, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
        dacl = sd.GetSecurityDescriptorDacl()   # instead of dacl = win32security.ACL()
        dacl.AddAccessAllowedAce(win32security.ACL_REVISION, con.FILE_ALL_ACCESS, userx)
        sd.SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(1, dacl, 0)
        win32security.SetFileSecurity(directory+'\\'+FILENAME, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, sd)
```

Comment: Is the directory we are allowing access to; M:\intra\EU'?
Do I have to put my credentials in LookupAccountName?

Comment: Those modules seem to be unavailable in Python3. I posted a different approach here as another answer.

Answer (score 11):

According to the NOTE of the [`os.chmod` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chmod):

> Although Windows supports chmod(), you can only set the file's
>   read-only flag with it (via the `stat.S_IWRITE` and `stat.S_IREAD`
>   constants or a corresponding integer value). All other bits are
>   ignored.

Comment: Thanks falsetru, Is there any other solution to that, how can i set permission so that other users can edit the files I create using some python script. My python scripts create some files in a shared directory, that I want other people to be able to edit as well. i cant do it manually as these are a lot of files. Any ideas how I can achieve that in windows

Answer (score 7):

The recommended solution didn't work on Python3 (modules not available). I took a different approach, to use the Windows command line.

In my case, I needed the "LOCAL SERVICE" account to have permission. I did:

```
    import subprocess
    args = ["icacls", directory,
            "/grant:r", 'LOCAL SERVICE:(OI)(CI)MF']
    subprocess.check_call(args)
```

Note that this permission seems to only work when set on a directory. For security reasons, it would also be a good idea to ensure that "directory" actually exists.

Also note that "LOCAL SERVICE" might go by a translated name. In German locale, for example, it is "Lokaler Dienst."