# Python Windows Create Folder Specifying Users

Tags: windows, python-3.x, directory

I know how to create a folder with certain permissions like this:

```
import os
os.mkdir('test',0o550)
```

But what if I want to only assign access to specific groups or users?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use [os.chown()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.chown) on the directory afterwords for unix/linux, for windows the [win32security module of pywin32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168110/setting-folder-permissions-in-windows-using-python)

Comment: Thanks. It says "Availability: Unix." under that section, though. Will it still work somehow?

Comment: I should have noticed the tag (Edit: And the title.. ugh), you may need win32security as [explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168110/setting-folder-permissions-in-windows-using-python).