# Python Restricting Access To Folders (Windows permissions)

Tags: windows, python-2.7, python-3.x, security, permissions

After multiplie tries, I've come up with no solution. I don't think you can manually just lock a folder and put a password assigned to it if that makes sense. I think you can, lock a folder using a password. But manually changing the permissions of the folder, (when you right click and go to security tab and deny every user to accessing the folder, aka denying everyone to modify and read & execute etc) what im trying to understand is how would you go about using python to deny everyone permissions on a windows folder?

My actual gui is pyqt4 but its sorted. I just dont understand how to set permissions on folders in windows 10. Thank you in advance.

Basic steps in my application.

Select folder (Done)
Enter password (Done)
Click lock folder button (Done)
Sets permissions to deny access (Need help)

And when you want to unlock the folder

Select folder (Done)
Enter password (Done)
Click unlock folder button (Done)
Removes deny permissions (Need help)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting folder permissions in Windows using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168110/setting-folder-permissions-in-windows-using-python)

Comment: @JoshLee I did see that, but couldn't make sense of it.

Comment: I added an [alternate answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43244697/205580) that may make more sense to you. It's at least a more proper solution in general.

Answer (score 0):

WE can actually do that stuff and here are the procedures:

1. Right-click inside the folder where the files you want to protect are located. The folder you want to hide can even be on your desktop.
2. Select "New" from the contextual menu.
3. Click on "Text Document."
4. Hit Enter. It doesn't matter what the file will be named. You can delete this text file once the lockable folder has been made.
5. Double-click the text file to open it.
6. Paste the below text into the new document:

   ```
   cls

   @ECHO OFF

   title Folder Locker

   if EXIST "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" goto UNLOCK

   if NOT EXIST Locker goto MDLOCKER

   :CONFIRM

   echo Are you sure u want to Lock the folder(Y/N)

   set/p "cho=>"

   if %cho%==Y goto LOCK

   if %cho%==y goto LOCK

   if %cho%==n goto END

   if %cho%==N goto END

   echo Invalid choice.

   goto CONFIRM

   :LOCK

   ren Locker "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"

   attrib +h +s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"

   echo Folder locked

   goto End

   :UNLOCK

   echo Enter password to Unlock folder

   set/p "pass=>"

   if NOT %pass%==Your-Password-Here goto FAIL

   attrib -h -s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"

   ren "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" Locker

   echo Folder Unlocked successfully

   goto End

   :FAIL

   echo Invalid password

   goto end

   :MDLOCKER

   md Locker

   echo Locker created successfully

   goto End
   ```
7. Find where it says "Your-Password-Here" in the document.

   8. Replace "Your-Password-Here" with the password you want to lock the folder with.
8. Click File.
9. "Select Save As..."
10. Click on the "Text Documents (*.txt)" menu bar that's next to "Save as type:"
11. Select "All Files"
12. Change the file name to "FolderLocker.bat"
13. Click "Save."
14. Double-click FolderLocker.
15. Fill the Locker folder with the items you want to protect.
16. Open the FolderLocker file, because it's time to lock that folder up!
17. Type "Y" into the screen.
18. Click Enter, and the Folder Locker window will disappear, along with the Locker folder itself! Your secrets are safe!

To unlock the folder, double-click "FolderLocker" to open it.
Enter the password you entered in Step 8, and click Enter.

The Locker folder is back. You can open it to find your hidden files. Repeat Steps 17, 18 and 19 to lock the folder again.