# Error with os.walk() on python 2.7

Tags: python

I have a problem with os.walk(path). Some folders seems that cannot Traversed. I have tried the `os.path.exists(path)` but i have an exception even thought the directory already exists. From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) is written that On some platforms, this function may return False if permission is not granted to execute `os.stat()` on the requested file, even if the path physically exists.

So i have tried os.stat(path) and i get an error The system cannot find the file specified.

Finally i have tried `os.listdir(path)` and i get a False message. so i have tried to do the following `x=os.listdir("C:\\Windows\\System32")` but the folder v1 wasn't inside the list x when i have searched with the `"v1" in x`

the code is the following

```
import os

path = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\v1"
os.stat(path)
```

The solutions that i came across are no use to solve my problem and i want to ask is there a possible way to get permissions to execute `os.stat()` to that specific folder and furthermore to do it via python?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're trying to access Sys32 which is probably locked under read-only permissions. Run this as well beforehand to try to remove the read-only flag :

```
subprocess.check_call(["attrib", "-r", path])
```

Be sure to run your program as an Administrator as you're on Windows. All chmod operations are available, **but are severely restricted** to setting the R flags to files created by yourself and that's it. In case that fails, I'll refer you to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168110/setting-folder-permissions-in-windows-using-python), you'll have to use modules.