# I tried this with os.chown, but it throws an error. Is there any other way to do this?

Tags: python

this is the code I'm trying to run in python 3.10:

```
def copyComplete(source, target):
    shutil.copy2(source, target)
    st = os.stat(source)
    os.chown(target, st.st_uid, st.st_gid)
```

It throws this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'chown'
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: What OS are you on? The `chown` function is documented as Unix-specific: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chown https://docs.python.org/3/library/intro.html#notes-on-availability

Comment: `copy2()` should already preserve file ownership.

Comment: I'm in windows, but the file I'm trying to copy doesn't let me write/append using *python code* with open('examplefile.json', 'a') as file: file.append('etc.')*exiting python code*, but instead throws permission error

Comment: This answer might be helpful; [PermissionError: Errno 13 Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36469464/8658598).

Answer (score 0):

`os.chown` doesnt exist for windows

you need to use something like

- another python package [link](https://pypi.org/project/oschmod/)
- use windows `takeown.exe` [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/takeown#remarks)
- win32security lib see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12168268/6727228)