# Recursive os.listdir?

Tags: python, directory

I'd like to get a list of all files in a directory recursively, with no directories.

Say there's a directory `~/files` with "a.txt", "b.txt", and a directory "c" with "d.txt" and "e" inside it, and "f.txt" inside e. How would I go about getting a list that looks like `['/home/user/files/a.txt', '/home/user/files/b.txt', '/home/user/files/c/d.txt', '/home/user/files/c/e/f.txt']`?

Comment: The paths to `d.txt` and `f.txt` that you specified don't exist, so...

Comment: See the second answer in the following and just remove the print dir_names http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918458/how-to-traverse-through-the-files-in-a-directory

Comment: Downvoted for being a FAQ

Comment: The answer that was a duplicate was about os.walk and glob.glob. So, those don't answer this question. This question is about os.listdir. Why? Because tests show os.listdir as creating a list of files faster than os.walk and glob.glob. Thanks.

Answer (score 84):

```
import os
[os.path.join(dp, f) for dp, dn, fn in os.walk(os.path.expanduser("~/files")) for f in fn]
```