# All possible directory paths within two levels

Tags: python

Suppose that I have a directory with 3 directories a, b, c. Within each of these directories I have the four directories 1, 2, 3, 4. Is there a way to list all paths, i.e. a/1,..., a/4, ..., c/1, ..., c/4, in python?

Is there a generalization? For example, given a directory to list all paths within at most 3 levels.

Comment: Yes, there is a way, e.g. with a nested loop. And yes, there's a generalization, e.g. with recursion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursive os.listdir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309667/recursive-os-listdir)

Comment: I was hoping for something more specific.

Comment: You may find this article helpful. [List directories with a specified depth in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7159607/9014308)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import os
n_levels = 2
cur_level = ['/your/start/path']
for level in range(n_levels):
  cur_level = [os.path.join(p, f) 
               for p in cur_level
               if os.path.isdir(p)
               for f in os.listdir(p)]
print(cur_level)
```

It starts at `cur_level = '/your/start/path'` as level 0, enumerates all its files and directories and stores their full paths back in list `cur_level`. Then the same is done for each path in the `cur_level` again, the results are again saved as a list.