# Python: Iterating over every file in directory

Tags: python, email

Using python, I am trying to take a list of emails in .txt format and delete anything after a specific keyword, "Original message", in order to delete the part that I sent. All of the emails are currently saved to a directory via a VBScript in Outlook. Each email is its own .txt file which I would like to cycle through them all in the one file.

If there is a way to replace all text between two keywords that would also work as I have a program that combines the emails into one long .txt file.

I apologize if I left out any important information, this is my first time posting here

Comment: Look into os.walk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to traverse through the files in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918458/how-to-traverse-through-the-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: If you can do VBA you can do Python. Should not be more than 20 lines. You can do it !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `os.listdir()` to iterate over the files in your directory:

```
import os

files = [i for i in os.listdir("Path/to/directory/storing/emails") if i.endswith("txt")]

for file in files:
    f = open(file).readlines()
    f = [i.strip('\n') for i in f]

    final_email = f[:f.index("Original message")] #this list slicing will remove the part containing "Original message" and below it

    final_message = '\n'.join(final_email)

    f = open(file, 'w')

    f.write(final_message)

    f.close()
```

Comment: You forgot the ending bracket (__]__) in your list comprehension.

Comment: @CristiFati Thank you for pointing that out. It is fixed now.